# Finding details of open socket

Tags: tcp, socket

My program is leaving TCP sockets open, and I'm trying to trace the cause (I use a number of different sockets).  The lsof commands shows:

```
myprog  258981 root   56u     sock                0,8      0t0 2429743 protocol: TCP
myprog  258981 root   57u     sock                0,8      0t0 2430142 protocol: TCP
myprog  258981 root   58u     sock                0,8      0t0 2430553 protocol: TCP
myprog  258981 root   59u     sock                0,8      0t0 2430975 protocol: TCP
myprog  258981 root   60u     sock                0,8      0t0 2431371 protocol: TCP
myprog  258981 root   61u     sock                0,8      0t0 2431775 protocol: TCP
```

So I *think* this means the last TCP socket is open at node 2431775.  So I'm trying to find more info for this socket.

How can I find more details of the socket (destination address & port)?

Answer (score 1):

A TCP socket doesn't have an inode number (maybe it does under Plan9). It's not "mapped" anywhere to a file system. You might be confusing this with UNIX domain sockets.

It's not clear what you hope to find in information. What happens is that your program creates a socket and doesn't properly dispose of it, plus, even if it does, a TCP state machine might linger, e.g. waiting for outstanding ACKs (depending on what you do and how your machine is configured). So, in your code, look where sockets are created. if you're confused *when* that happens, `strace` might be helpful.

Comment: Can I find out the destination IP and port number of these open sockets?  (Just need info to help me trace which socket is left open)

Comment: I close the socket upon socket error - so I assume not waiting for outstanding ACKS

Comment: "A TCP socket doesn't have an inode number" yes, it has. @TSG: Information about sockets can be retrieved via the `sock_diag(7)` netlink interface on Linux. A (quite awkward and limited) command line interface to that is the `ss` program from util-linux. `ss -e` will also tell you the inode number.

Comment: @UncleBilly I'm surprised! through / on which file system is that inode?

Comment: Running `ss  -putn | grep <port>` will give some details - easiest way...

Comment: @MarcusMüller [sockfs](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c#L345); just like other internal filesystem, it's a a fs without *directories*, where inodes are only linked to from open files. As to plan9, (natively) it doesn't knoww about either sockets or inodes ;-)

Comment: "ss -putn" is showing  me established connections only...but I suspect my sockets are open but never established.  ss lists only 2 sockets related to my app, but I have 100+ open sockets (according to lsof).  Is there way to show ALL sockets for my process?